# What is the use of backslash in C program initialization?

Tags: c, syntax, escaping

1. Without backslash

   ```
   unsigned char a=5;
   ```
2. With backslash

   ```
   unsigned char a=\
   5;
   ```

Given that both are working identically, then what is the actual use of backslash?

Comment: It is telling the preprocessor to concatenate the two lines. But C doesn't mind these two lines to be separate.

Comment: Have you tried searching this on a search engine?

Comment: The slash preceding a new line indicates that it should be treated as one line.  I don't think it's necessary for this type of statement, but is often seen when dealing with a multiline preprocessor macro

Comment: @babon: Given the backslash, it’s hell to search for.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Agreed. But searching with the title - "what is the use of backslash in c program" would have been easier :)

Comment: @babon : when i tried on search engine it end with escape character result.

Answer (score 4):

A `\` character at the end of a line means that the following line should be treated as the continuation of the previous line.

Since you're allowed to have whitespaces after the assignment (`=`) operator, it's pointless in this case.

Comment: Important to note that the _preprocessor_ does this. It is not defined in C, but the C compiler will never see it because the preprocessor processed it away.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: But the behaviour is clearly defined by the C standard in section 5.1.1.2, paragraph 1, subpoint 2. (Which is not, according to many interpretations, part of the "preprocessor", since that is often understood as implementing only phase 4 in that same paragraph. In any case, that's also part of the C standard.)

Comment: @rci, At least until point 5, the secion is about "preprocessing translation units".

Answer (score 1):

The C Standard describes the second phase of program translation this way:

> **5.1.1.2 Translation phases**
>
> ...
>
> 2. Each instance of a backslash character (`\`) immediately followed by a new-line character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to form logical source lines. Only the last backslash on any physical source line shall be eligible for being part of such a splice. A source file that is not empty shall end in a new-line character, which shall not be immediately preceded by a backslash character before any such splicing takes place.

Hence there is no semantic difference between the 2 code fragments posted. These backslash new-line sequences can occur in the middle of a token too:

```
\
u\
ns\
ign\
ed c\
har a\
 = 5;/\
/comment
```